# Making a template function mirror its template argument's signature

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates, template-meta-programming

I have a template function:

```cpp
template <??? func>
??? wrapper(??? args) {
    // ... Stuff
    return func(args);
}
```

It should have the same signature as the `func` non-type template parameter.

The closest I've gotten is using `auto` in the template declaration and then using some form of function traits to deduce the return type, however, this method does not allow for deducing the parameters as a whole.

Ideally,

```cpp
template <typename R, typename... Args, R(*func)(Args...)>
R wrapper(Args&&... args); // ...
```

or some other imaginary syntax would A. be allowed and B. deduce `R` and `Args` from `func`.

`func` *must* be specified at compile time and the function may not have any additional parameters (I need to take the address of the wrapper).

At this point I feel like my current solution,

```cpp
template <auto func, typename... Args>
auto wrapper(Args&&... args) {
    return func(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

cannot be improved, since it appears impossible to generate "pure" variadic template arguments (getting them back after "storing" them anywhere (e.g. a `tuple`)). Which is sad, because it forces the `Args` to be provided manually. But of course I'd love to see someone prove me wrong on this!

Comment: It's not entirely clear to me what you're trying to achieve. Could you add an example function and how you would like to use `wrapper`?

Comment: Your current solution look pretty fine. What is your "pure" variadic template idea about? If you store the arguments data somewhere, the types are known and you can store them in a tuple and you can `std::apply` them to a callable. And by passing a callable to a template, the arguments to the callable are also known. I simply can't catch your problem unless you give us a better idea what is your use case. Can you please explain a bit... maybe with some pseudo code? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create traits to extract returs type and parameters. issue would be to handle arity only from function declaration.

If you can wrap in a class/functor, it would be possible:

```cpp
template <auto func> struct wrapper_t;

template <typename Ret, typename ... Ts, Ret (*func)(Ts...)>
struct wrapper_t<func>
{
    Ret operator() (Ts... args) const { return func(std::forward<Ts>(args)...); }
};

// handle ellipsis functions ala printf
template <typename Ret, typename ... Ts, Ret (*func)(Ts..., ...)>
struct wrapper_t<func>
{
    template <typename ...EllipsisArgs>
    Ret operator() (Ts... args, EllipsisArgs&&... ellipisisArgs) const {
        return func(std::forward<Ts>(args)...,
                    std::forward<EllipsisArgs>(ellipisisArgs)...);
    }
};

template <auto func>
constexpr wrapper_t<func> wrapper{};
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/rchrPcK6W)

Comment: I totally did not consider the ability to partially specialize non-type template arguments. Thank you!!